# Need to figure out total hours between check-in and check-out times

Tags: php, sql, database, insert

I am trying to create a check-in/check-out table in my database. My check-in form works without issue, inserting the time into my database. The problem occurs when I try to check out. Everything is good on the first entry...

[image]

But when I try to check in and check out again, this happens...

[image]

So far so good, but when I check out...

[image]
Currently, my code updates the `out` column and `totalTime` column of all matching `child_id`'s.

Here is my code:

```
// Select the correct child from the database
$sql_childID = "SELECT id FROM child
                WHERE firstName = '$childFirstName'
                AND lastName = '$childLastName'";
$result = $pdo->query($sql_childID);
$row = $result->fetch();
$var = $row['id'];

// Insert the check out time for the child
$query = "UPDATE checkinout
        SET `out` = :nowTime
        WHERE child_id = $var
        AND `in` IS NOT NULL";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':nowTime', date("YmjHis"));
$statement->execute();

// Select check in time for specified child
$sql_inTime = "SELECT `in` FROM checkinout
        WHERE child_id = $var";
$inResult = $pdo->query($sql_inTime);
$inRow = $inResult->fetch();
$inTime = strtotime($inRow['in']);

// Select the check out time for specified child
$sql_outTime = "SELECT `out` FROM checkinout
        WHERE child_id = $var";
$outResult = $pdo->query($sql_outTime);
$outRow = $outResult->fetch();
$outTime = strtotime($outRow['out']);

// Find total hours
$totalTime = abs($outTime - $inTime)/(60*60);

// Update totalHours column for specified child
$queryTotalTime = "UPDATE checkinout
                SET totalTime = :totalTime
                WHERE child_id = $var
                AND 'out' IS NOT NULL";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($queryTotalTime);
$statement->bindValue(':totalTime', $totalTime);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Is child_id the id of the user? If so, how can someone check-in two times without checking out?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to PHP so the form doesn't have any validation. You technically could check-in twice. I'm trying to figure out the logic of inserting the check out time and total hours without affecting other rows in the process.

Comment: yes, child_id is id of the user. In the form, you would type in a first and last name and either check-in or check-out the child

Comment: Let me edit my pictures to be more accurate...

Comment: So you want only one record updated when checking out? If so, I think the problem is with: AND `in` IS NOT NULL. Should that be `out` rather than `in`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do all of this in your first update statement using [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) rather than figuring the total time with PHP:

```sql
UPDATE checkinout
SET 
    out = NOW(),
    totalTime = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `in`, NOW()) / 3600
WHERE
    child_id = $var
    AND out IS NULL
```

The criteria `WHERE out IS NULL` will only update rows that do not have a value in the `out` column yet.

Comment: Thank you, this code works perfectly for my purposes.

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed that I edited the answer just as you accepted it. The edited version should give you the fractional hour in the same format you currently have it.

Comment: Awesome! I changed it to MINUTE at first because I wasn't sure how to get that format back to how it was. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

IF you have MySQL Db THEN sql will be

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,in,out) from checkinout;
```